# Continuity Proof using Extreme Value or Intermediate Value Thm

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f and g are defined and finite valued on an open interval I which contains a, f is continuous at a, and f(a)≠0. Then g is continuous at a iff fg is continuous at a.

How would I prove this? I'm not exactly sure where to start> I'm assuming I use either Extreme or Intermediate Value Thm, but don't know which or when.

Comment: I don't believe either of those theorems are relevant here. The have continuity as a premise, not a conclusion.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen are there theorems that you suggest then?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

What you need basically is the theorems for continuity of products and quotients. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$, then $fg$ is. Conversely if $f$ and $h\equiv fg$ are continuous and $f\ne 0$ at $a$ then $g= h/f$ is.